# how to find and replace special url patern (Markdown syntax to HTML) by re module in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I want to search this string to find special pattern containing URL and it's name and then I need to change it's format:

Input string:

```
'Thsi is my [site](http://example.com/url) you can watch it.'
```

Output string:

```
'This is my <a href="http://example.com/url">site</a> you can watch it.'
```

The string may have several URLs and I need to change the format of every one and `site` is in unicode and can be every character in any language.

What pattern should be used and how I can do it?

Comment: That's Markdown syntax; why don't you use a Markdown parser?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, I need to change the format of user input string to work in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
import re
A = 'Thsi is my [site](http://example.com/url) you can watch it.'

site = re.compile( "\[(.*)\]" ).search(A).group(1)
url = re.compile( "\((.*)\)" ).search(A).group(1)

print A.replace("[{0}]".format(site), "").replace("({0})".format(url), '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(url, site))
```

**Output:**

```
Thsi is my <a href="http://example.com/url">site</a> you can watch it.
```

**Update as request in Comments:**

```
s = 'my [site](site.com) is about programing (python language)'
site, url =  s[s.find("[")+1:s.find(")")].split("](")
print s.replace("[{0}]".format(site), "").replace("({0})".format(url), '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(url, site))
```

**Output:**

```
my <a href="site.com">site</a> is about programing (python language)
```

Comment: Thanks, but only this format [..](..) is acceptable and should be changed to html, not (..) or [..] alonely.

Comment: for example:
input: `'my [site](site.com) is about programing (python language)'`
output:`'my <a href="site.com) is about programing (python language">site</a>'`
so this is not exactly the output I expected.

Comment: Updated solution. without regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a markdown expert, but if this is indeed markdown that you're trying to replace, and *not your own syntax*, you should use an appropriate parser. Note that, if you paste your string directly into stackoverflow - which also uses markdown - it will be transformed into a link, so it would clearly be valid markdown.

If it is indeed your own format, however, try the following to transform

```
'This is my [site](http://example.com/url) you can watch it.'
```

into

```
'This is my <a href="http://example.com/url">site</a> you can watch it.'
```

using the following match:

```
\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)
```

and the following replacement regex:

```
<a href="\\2">\\1<\/a>
```

In python, `re.sub(match, replace, stringThatYouWantToReplaceStuffIn)` should do the trick. Don't forget to assign the return value of `re.sub` to whatever variable should contain the new string.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to regex, I will check your pattern. if this work I'll mark your answer as true.